# How to select row with max value if the value of one column is the same?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here's the query:

```
SELECT ActionTicketID, OrderTicketID, BarCode, MAX(ID) AS ID, TicketBarCode
FROM Table
where ActionTicketID = 26250347
GROUP BY ActionTicketID, OrderTicketID, BarCode, ID, TicketBarCode
```

The result looks as the following:

[image]

As you can see I get 3 rows, but need only one where ID is max. I think it is because of ActionTicketID is the same.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `order by`;

```
SELECT top 1 ActionTicketID, OrderTicketID, BarCode, ID, TicketBarCode
FROM Table
where ActionTicketID = 26250347
order by ID desc
```